# How do I count the number of child objects and pass the calculated index to the child object?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, loops, ecmascript-6

My data looks something like below

```
  team1 : {
         author92 : "John" , 
         author43 : "Smith" 
        },
  team2 : {
         author33 : "Dolly", 
         author23 : "Mark" 
        },
```

And my desired to display Authors by group like below but add author counter regardless of the teams

**Group 1**
  1, John
  2, Smith
**Group 2**
  3, Dolly
  4, Mark

My current display is like this

**Group 1**
  1, John
  2, Smith
**Group 2**
  1, Dolly
  2, Mark

I have no control about the structure of the data but I am first looping through teams and passing data to a component in a React app.

```
{Object.values(data).map((key) => {
   return ( 
     <p>Group <span>{key + 1}</span></p>
     <Team authorCounter={} />
    )
}
```

And my Team component loops through posts and displays the authors

```
  const author = Object.keys(data.team1).map((key) => {
  return {
    <b>{key + 1}.</b> }
```

I am wondering how I can pass the number of authors added on top of each other so that I can start numbering authors in the child component.

Comment: You just want to display a number next to every author which corresponds to its position in the array ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the data is not in a usable state for your component, I would suggest you map the data first to a usable state, and precalculate the indexes.

This could pose a problem with sorting and reversing, but that would rather suggest you need to move the mapping to the `GroupContainer` component rather than outside of it

```js
const data = { 
  team1 : {
         author92 : "John" , 
         author43 : "Smith" 
        },
  team2 : {
         author33 : "Dolly", 
         author23 : "Mark" 
        }
};

const Member = ({ member }) => {
  return <p>{ member.index}, { member.name }</p>;
};

const Group = ({ index, teams }) => {
  return <div><p>Group { index }</p>{ teams.map( team => <Member member={team} /> ) }</div>;
};

class GroupContainer extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let counter = 0, childCounter = 0;
    let { data } = this.props;
    return <div>{ data.map( group => <Group {...group} /> ) }</div>;
  }
}

function mapData( data, childCount = 0 ) {
  return Object.keys( data ).map( (group, index) => {
    let obj = data[group];
    return {
      index: index + 1,
      name: group,
      teams: Object.keys( obj ).map( author => ({
        index: ++childCount,
        name: obj[author]
      }) )
    };
  });
}

ReactDOM.render( <GroupContainer data={ mapData( data ) } />, document.querySelector('#app') );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
</div>
```

Comment: I am trying to implement this on my app and I am having problems understanding mapData what exactly is happening there

Comment: @EmbetIsit It just transforms the data to a format you can really use in your UI, so you receive an array of groups, that contain an array of team members. They already contain the numbering so your UI only has to display it

Answer (score 2):

A working code for you. You can use functional components instead if you don't need state.

https://jsfiddle.net/sfr7hmf3/

```
const obj = {
  team1 : {
    author92 : "John" , 
    author43 : "Smith" 
  },
  team2 : {
    author33 : "Dolly", 
    author23 : "Mark" 
  },
};

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const teams = [];
    let teamNum = 1;
    let authorsStartWith = 1;

    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
      teams.push({
        team: obj[key],
        teamNum,
        authorsStartWith,
      });
      teamNum += 1;
      authorsStartWith += Object.keys(obj[key]).length;
    });

    return (
      <div>
        {
          teams.map(team =>
            <Team
              team={team.team}
              teamNum={team.teamNum}
              authorsStartWith={team.authorsStartWith}
              key={team.teamNum}
            />
          )
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}


class Team extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Group {this.props.teamNum}</p>
        <ol start={this.props.authorsStartWith}>
          {
            Object.values(this.props.team)
              .map(authorName =>
                    <li
                    key={`${this.props.groupName}_${authorName}`}
                  >
                    {authorName}
                  </li>)
          }
        </ol>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a closure over the count and increment while using an [increment operator `++`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Increment_()).

Comment: how do i do that?